# hover effect on two rows in one paragraph not working

Tags: css

I have a `<p>` containing two `<span>`s,
and I want one of them to float right, and each to be on an individual line (achieved by `display:block`).

on hover, they both should be highlighted, so I have put a `:hover` on the surrounding `<p>`.

Still, only one `span` gets highlighted.

Why? And how can I change it?

https://jsfiddle.net/o8wk7n8t/

Thank you

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/o8wk7n8t/1/

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set layout of `.parent` with `overflow: hidden` as you are using `float`.

```
.parent {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```css
.parent {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.parent:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

.right {
  float:right;
}

.left,
.right {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<p class="parent">
 <span class="left">Hi</span>
 <span class="right">Ho</span>
</p>
```

Comment: it works, thanks :) can you explain why? what exactly does overflow have to do with this?

Comment: @devman Always remember to set layout of parent elements whenever you use float on children. `overflow: hidden` sets layout of parent. There are many other ways to set layout as well. You can read about other ways to set layout here.. http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html